# Is it possible to create a asp.net project from existing published files?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, projects-and-solutions, bin

I am currently making changes to a site but only have access to the files on the FTP, Is it possible to build a project file and solution from these files so that i can code and then republish and deploy?

I have a list of files including a bin and App_Code file along with all the pages, How do i create a project from this?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

as much i know only you can do in this scenario that add all the dlls to your new project and use some OOPs concepts *(like overloading, overriding etc)* to use all the functionality of existing project.

happy coding :D